# Crash at System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalInterop.RoGetActivationFactory C#

Tags: c#, uwp, crash

I am getting below unhandled exception when I am opening my UWP app in x64 PC,

```
2021-03-25 14:46:09.77 | [Bixby | App.xaml.cs | App | App_UnhandledException | 58]  Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs
2021-03-25 14:46:10.04 | [Bixby | App.xaml.cs | App | App_UnhandledException | 59]     at System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalInterop.RoGetActivationFactory(String, Guid&, IntPtr&) + 0x197
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.FactoryCache.GetActivationFactoryInternal(String, RuntimeTypeHandle, ContextEntry) + 0x4a
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.FactoryCache.GetActivationFactory(String, RuntimeTypeHandle, Boolean) + 0x6c
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.McgMarshal.GetActivationFactory(String, RuntimeTypeHandle) + 0x24
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.McgMarshal.ActivateInstance(String) + 0x36
   at WREN_SDK.WRENAPI..ctor() + 0x1c
   at UWPBixbyClient.CoreService.WRENSDKServiceHandler..ctor() + 0x24
   at UWPBixbyClient.CoreService.WRENSDKServiceHandler.GetInstance() + 0x62
   at UWPBixbyClient.UWPBixbyClient_XamlTypeInfo.XamlTypeInfoProvider.Activate_80_Greeting() + 0x29
   at UWPBixbyClient.UWPBixbyClient_XamlTypeInfo.XamlUserType.ActivateInstance() + 0x29
   at UWPBixbyClient!<BaseAddress>+0x1480aac
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.McgMarshal.ThrowOnExternalCallFailed(Int32, RuntimeTypeHandle) + 0x21
   at __Interop.ComCallHelpers.Call(__ComObject, RuntimeTypeHandle, Int32, Type__Impl.UnsafeType, Void*) + 0xce
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.INavigate__Impl.Stubs.Navigate(__ComObject, Type) + 0x72
   at UWPBixbyClient.OnBoarding.ViewModels.IntroViewModel.<MoveNextPage>b__5_0() + 0xdc
   at Windows.UI.Core.DispatchedHandler.Invoke() + 0x25
   at UWPBixbyClient!<BaseAddress>+0x149a7ec
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() + 0x21
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task) + 0x70
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task) + 0x38
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task) + 0x17
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() + 0xb
   at UWPBixbyClient.OnBoarding.ViewModels.IntroViewModel.<MoveNextPage>d__5.MoveNext() + 0xf1
```

**What is the cause of this issue and how can I resolve it?**

Comment: How can I know which DLL are missing in my target PC?

Comment: Could you please confirm your target platform? Is it x86 or x64?

Comment: @AryaDing-MSFT the target platform is x64

Comment: Have you use [Application.UnhandledException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application.unhandledexception?view=winrt-19041) event to see if it could get more unhandled exception information?

Comment: @AryaDing-MSFT we already have stack trace, this info was actually taken from global unhandled exception...

Comment: Could you please provide us a [mcve] by OneDrive or GitHub?